# passing an extra parameter in URL using jquery autocomplete

Tags: jquery, jquery-autocomplete

i am trying to send an extra parameter (other than the typed key) to my controller using jquery Autocomplete , i tried to append it to the url like below but for some reason the parameter is always empty, here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#classDefNode').each(function() {

    $(this).autocomplete({
            type:"POST",
            serviceUrl: '${pageContext.request.contextPath}/getClassDefinitionName?interfaceName='+$("#interfaceDefNodeIOS").val(),
            paramName: "className",
            delimiter: ",",


            transformResult: function(response) {
            return {        
              //must convert json to javascript object before process
              suggestions: $.map($.parseJSON(response), function(item) {

                  return { value: item.name, data: item.id };
               })

             };

                }

         });
});
});
```

i think that the problem is that the .ready(function()) is executed when the page load and at the time the input is still empty.
i also tried to use boostrap typeahead but i couldn't make it work, it showed bad request in chrome console.
many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are initializing the autocomplete objects with `serviceUrl: 'stuff'+$("#interfaceDefNodeIOS").val()`. At init time, $("#interfaceDefNodeIOS") is empty, right? So you init the autocompletes with an empty parameter. This parameter won't automatically get updated as you type something in the input fields. The autocompletes are already initialized.

From [the doc](https://github.com/devbridge/jQuery-Autocomplete), use :

> params: Additional parameters to pass with the request, optional.

Comment: Yep? Nope? No news? OP's gone?

Comment: thnx a lot , i solved my problem by using bootstrap typeahead plugin. i will update my post later in the evening.